# How does one set up a shared feed amongst all users?

Tags: getstream-io

I want to set up a shared team feed that allows multiple users to post to. An example is using the `to` field as described in the docs, where `some_team` is a `feed`:

`'to': ['some_team']`

I would like to provide each user with a *single Stream generated token* that enables them to create their own posts, comment on others' posts, and like others' posts on this feed. I would also like them to be able to view all posts on this feed. This is basically how I'd imagine a shared feed works on facebook, etc...

However, base on the Rest API documentation, this doesn't seem possible with the constructs for generating tokens:

`The resource field of the JWT payload allows you to define which API endpoints can be accessed, you can pick *one* of the following [resources]:`

For example, I can create a user called `username`, and provide it read access to all resources (feed, activities, etc...) on `some_teamusername`, but this would prevent write access to new activities for that user.

```
token = client.create_user_token("username", **{
        "resource": "*", <--- must be one 
        "action": "read", <--- singular relationship to resource
        "feed_id": "some_teamusername"});
```

There should be a simple way to permit read access of others' posts on a shared feed but allow write access to your own content (posts, comments, likes).

Answer (score 0):

I can make that feed group globally writable if that's what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a `feed` (e.g. timeline:teamname) that several people can use, much like a typical Facebook group. People can write/modify/delete their own posts/comments/likes but only read everyone else's posts/comments/likes. However, it looks like all feeds are created for a specific user (e.g. `client.feed('timeline', 'teamname')`, and cannot be shared. Me calling it `teamname` doesn't work as `teamname` isn't going to be a specific user that can use a token for `teamname`.

Comment: Would a globally writable `feed group` mean that all users have write access (and can delete) others' posts/comments/likes? Again, my objective is that people can write/modify/delete their own posts/comments/likes but only read everyone else's posts/comments/likes.

Comment: When it's globally writable, there's no modify allowed for any user, and delete is only allowed to the user that posted.

Comment: I assume this is required to get `targetting` (https://getstream.io/docs/#targetting) to work for the Use Case: Organizations and Topics? If the targeted feed is not global, then no one can write to it, correct?

Comment: How can I submit a ticket to get a feed group globally writable? I would like this done for the user `hhsuey`, app `selfiegoals`, and feed group `timeline`